# mvc implementing page that is viewed only once

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to implement a terms and conditions page for my site that requires the user to accept the terms and conditions and probably stores that value in a cookie so I can tell if they have accepted and not continually prompt them, not all users will have accounts so I think a cookie is the way to go there.

Just trying to think of the best way to accomplish this, would it be best with a global filter that executes before any action on the site and redirects to the terms and conditions page (saving somewhere the page that was requested) if the user has not logged in, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why not use a session? Session["AcceptedTC"] = true; Then implement an attribute that would check session before calling an action.

Comment: A cookie can be persisted longer than a session.

Comment: You then have a problem if T&C change - the cookie might not expire for the next few days and user won't be aware that T&C have changed.

Comment: You can always put the T&C version into the cookie, and check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In action method that will process T&C POST:

```
Session["AcceptedTC"] = true;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AcceptedTermsCheck : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Check if AcceptedTC is set to true

        // If set, then do nothing

        // Otherwise redirect to TC page
    }
}
```

Reason for using an attribute, is that you might have some pages that won't require users to accept terms and conditions. If you were to do a check on Application_BeginRequest then you won't have that flexibility.

Comment: this is pretty much what I was thinking, and then adding some whitelist attribute to flag actions that dont need to show the page like the terms and conditions page itself, I think I've seen something similar done with global authorisation filters

Comment: thinking about it I'll probably use the profile api for the flagging if the user has already seen the t&c as it works for anonymous and logged in users

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option is to override the Application_BeginRequest method on the global.asax file.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(ShouldIShowMessage())
   {
       this.Response.Redirect("RedirectUrl");
   }
}

private bool ShouldIShowMessage()
{
   // Decision logic here
}
```

**EDIT**
Ive just thought, to clarify your decision logic would still require something like say a cookie, but it saves having to decorate controllers with an attribute or adding a global filter.